# How can I populate my Swift App with data from a webpage?

Tags: swift, sorting, url, wiki, ipados

I wanted to create an app that organizes and displays the data I want in a fandom wiki for me, so I downloaded Swift Playgrounds on an iPad Pro, finished all the tutorials, and I’m working on it now. I’m already decently familiar with C/C++/C#, Java, Python, and a couple other languages (not Objective-C), but the Swift tutorials only really covered the basics and `View`s, and didn’t really get into the unique Swift coding. Although I could manually input all the data and make the app work faster and offline, that’d be a huge pain, and the data on the wiki could change as the game updates.

I’ve searched for how here and with general web searches for several other sites, but not a single one of the methods described worked and provided me with something usable. Some old Objective-C guides indicated base capabilities of sorting webpage source data and generating tables (arrays of arrays) of `String`s with data from a webpage table, but I couldn’t find anything on a Swift equivalent. Thus I’m assuming I’ll have to write my own sorting functions. I wont have trouble with that so long as I can get a String with the up to date source code from the webpage, but that’s the part I can’t seem to get.

Of all the methods I saw and tried (all of which failed) I like this one the best:

```
var source = String(contentsOf: URL(string: String)!, encoding: .ascii)
```

*Where `String` is the copy-pasted URL in quotation marks.*

I get an error saying it can throw, and that that’s not allowed in a property initializer, and I’d like a way around that, but even if I have:

```
let address = URL(string: String)
var source = String(contentsOf: address, encoding: .ascii)
```

It tells me, “Cannot use instance member ‘address’ within property initializer; property initializer run before ‘self’ is available.” If I separate the `String` out to a `let` above that one the error comes up on the second `let`. The Swift tutorials didn’t even explain what the difference between `let` and `var` was, but through past error messages I’m guessing `let` is a “const var.” Regardless of which I use the error doesn’t change.

This one provided me with a useless `String` containing `"application/octet-stream"`, but was the only one that didn’t cause an error:

```
var resources = UTType(filenameExtension: URL(string: String)!.pathExtension)?.preferredMIMEType ?? "application/octet-stream"
```

I’ve never seen `??` before so I had to look that up. My understanding is that it’s an operator in Swift used to identify a default for if the other is `nil`, but let me know if I’m wrong. I don’t understand the UTType or MIMEType very well either.

The tutorials also didn’t explain the `?` and `!` in these kinds of uses. I would have guessed pointers, but given the use of `var` and rumors I’ve heard I think Swift is more like C# with the whole lack of pointers. If not pointers (data vs memory address) then I’m guessing there’s like a “raw” and “stable” form based on past errors I’ve gotten. Where `?` brings it down to the “raw” form and `!` brings it up to the “stable” form.

Comment: “ I would have guessed pointers ” There’s no need to guess. I’d suggest you read [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html)

Comment: So what appears to be an unofficial guide to Swift is going to better than the 60 hours of Swift coding tutorial and 10 hours of Swift UI tutorials provided by Apple that I already did?

Comment: Oh and by the way I already looked for it there. It’s not under operators so I don’t know what they are.

Comment: Look under “Optionals”.

Comment: After searching through dozens of pages I found that they’re classified as independent data types for some reason, and named “unwrapped” and “wrapped,” but otherwise work exactly as I guessed: “…`?` brings it down to the “[wrapped]” form and `!` brings it up to the “[unwrapped]” form.” I still don’t understand why they exist though. The guide only says that “unwrapped” works exactly like “wrapped” except that it causes runtime errors if the value is nil. So why have those “data types” at all, and why force its use in for example the `String(contentsOf: URL!)`?

Comment: @PålHart Look at the domain. The Swift Programming Language ("TSPL") isn't some random blog, it's the de-facto canonical introductory material for learning the language. Other Apple resources typically focus on their particular frameworks, and typically assume familiarity with the lang.

Comment: @PålHart Don't be so quick to dismiss things you don't understand, there are good reasons for it that you just don't appreciate yet. Maybe you never will, but you have to be open to it. They're not called "wrapped" and "unwrapped". It's a data type called `Optional` (well it's generic, so formally, `Optional<Wrapped>`). It must be a decent idea, because Rust, C#, Java, Python and C++ have all introduced it in some flavor or another.

Comment: See also: ["the blub paradox"](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html): "... But when our hypothetical Blub programmer looks in the other direction, up the power continuum, he doesn't realize he's looking up. What he sees are merely weird languages. He probably considers them about equivalent in power to Blub, but with all this other hairy stuff thrown in as well. Blub is good enough for him, because he thinks in Blub."

Comment: You mean not Apple.com? How about the author credit of “The Swift Community” rather than Apple. After further researching it Apple Inc. does own the copyright on the website, but those indications pointed to them not being directly involved. Based on those indicators it was more likely to be unaffiliated with Apple. Furthermore what would be the point of developing all those tutorials if they weren’t going to teach all the useful basics included in that documentation?

Comment: `Optional<Wrapped>` is code-statement, not the name. The full English names are “Wrapped Optional Type” and “Unwrapped Optional Type.” My original post identified them as states (which they are) and I was obviously specifying the states. Which are “wrapped” and “unwrapped.” Here’s the page it’s on: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html 

In any case Apple left it out of the tutorial for some reason. Also I don’t see anything on here about the SwiftUI nor accessing data from the internet. It’s almost all just stuff that was covered in the coding tutorials.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245372/discussion-between-alexander-and-pal-hart).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the code, and figured out a solution to the minor annoyance at the same time.

```
var data = (try? String(contentsOf: URL(string: String)!))!
```

The “Cannot use instance member ‘address’ within property initializer; property initializer run before ‘self’ is available” error is fixed by not having a separate variable for the `URL`; which I thought having was annoying anyway. Using `try?` converts the value to `nil` if an error is thrown, fixing the limitation of throws not being allowed in the property initializer. This outputs the wrapped (what I referred to as “raw” in the original post; due to not knowing the terminology yet) version of the datatype, so I have to convert it to the unwrapped (what I referred to as “stable” in the original post) version of the datatype in order to use it.

I think a better/cleaner solution than the concept of wrapped and unwrapped optional datatypes would be designing methods to be able to handle throws, but I guess inventing problems to have solutions for is just how Swift rolls. I also noticed that despite what the guides indicated, the encoding does not need to be specified for what I need to accomplish. I should be able to finish the rest of it now.